# Converting Nested Dictionaries and flatten merge

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334'}},
 {'profile': {'mid': '767327'}},
 {'personal_information': {'mobile': '7654362'}},
 {'profile': {'business_name': 'ABG'}}]
```

I want my output as:

```
{"personal_information":{'merchant_id': '5334', 'mobile': '7654362'},
 "profile":{'mid':'767327', 'business_name': 'ABG'}}
```

I need to group based on keys and update the dictionaries.

Comment: @Chris there doesn't seem to be anything here to groupby.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dictionaries and if you've encountered that key before call `dict.update` otherwise add a new entry.

```
data = [
    {'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334'}},
    {'profile': {'mid': '767327'}},
    {'personal_information': {'mobile': '7654362'}},
    {'profile': {'business_name': 'ABG'}}
]

result = {}
for sub in data:
    for key, value in sub.items():
        if key in result:
            result[key].update(value)
        else:
            result[key] = value
```

Output

```
>>> result
{
    'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334', 'mobile': '7654362'},
    'profile': {'mid': '767327', 'business_name': 'ABG'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!, I was trying a key grouby, but this was straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Kind of messy looking but you can use `collections.defaultdict` and since every dict is a single key dict you can do this all in one loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in map(next, map(iter, map(dict.items, data))):
    result[key].update(value)
 
print(dict(result))
```

---

```
{'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334', 'mobile': '7654362'}, 'profile': {'mid': '767327', 'business_name': 'ABG'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dictionaries in the list only have one entry, you can loop over a mapping that gets their first/only item:

```
L = [{'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334'}},
 {'profile': {'mid': '767327'}},
 {'personal_information': {'mobile': '7654362'}},
 {'profile': {'business_name': 'ABG'}}]

D = dict()
for k,v in map(max,map(dict.items,L)):
    D.setdefault(k,dict()).update(v)

print(D)
{'personal_information': {'merchant_id': '5334', 'mobile': '7654362'},
 'profile': {'mid': '767327', 'business_name': 'ABG'}}
```